# Error during run OrganizationRequest 'RetrieveAllEntities'

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I got this error during execute, could anyone give suggestion? Thanks

```
OrganizationRequest oreq = new OrganizationRequest();
oreq.RequestName = "RetrieveAllEntities";// please google for available Request Names
oreq.Parameters = new ParameterCollection();
oreq.Parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("EntityFilters", EntityFilters.Entity));
oreq.Parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("RetrieveAsIfPublished", false));

OrganizationResponse respo = orgProxy.Execute(oreq);
```

*"The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:ExecuteResult. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 727. Element 'schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic:value' contains data of the 'schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Metadata:ArrayOfEntityMetadata' data contract. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this contract. Add the type corresponding to 'ArrayOfEntityMetadata' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details."*

Comment: Providing more information about your problem would be much helpful. This is not a debugging forum.

Comment: Hi hawk can you give example what additional information I should be added? Thanks

Comment: Information like what are you trying to achieve? Did you try any method to solve the problem?

Comment: why don't use a `RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest`?

Comment: Hi Guido, I cannot use RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest because I am trying to access CRM 2011/2013 with .net 3.5 project, the SDK lib cannot be used because they are .net 4

Comment: next time put this information before in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference to `Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy` and `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk`. Visual Studio may tell you that you need to add an additional couple `System.*` references - add them.

Use this code:

```
        IOrganizationService service = GetCrmService(connectionString); //This is a helper, just need to setup the service
        var request = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages.RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest() 
            { 
                EntityFilters = Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata.EntityFilters.All, 
                RetrieveAsIfPublished = false 
            };

        var response = (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages.RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse)service.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get it work finally there is two KnownTypeAttribute need to be added to the proxy class

```
**[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(EntityMetadata[]))]**
public partial class OrganizationRequest : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
....

**[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(EntityMetadata[]))]**
public partial class OrganizationResponse : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
```

Thank you for help.